# Why Parcel.writeBoolean(boolean) doesn't exist?

Tags: android, parcel

When I need to write a `boolean` to a `Parcel`, I do this:

```
@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeInt(myBoolean ? 1 : 0);
}
```

But, is there any reason for the method `writeBoolean` not exists?

Comment: if you really want, use `writeValue`

Comment: Maybe you can take a look at this: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=5973

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pack your boolean values into a byte using masking and shifting. That would be the most efficient way to do it and is probably what they would expect you to do.

Check the Primitives section of this link https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel.html

to parcel your boolean  values.. you can use http://www.parcelabler.com/

ex:

```
class BooleanSample {
    Boolean flag;
}
```

result:

```
class BooleanSample implements Parcelable {
    Boolean flag;

    protected BooleanSample(Parcel in) {
        byte flagVal = in.readByte();
        flag = flagVal == 0x02 ? null : flagVal != 0x00;
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        if (flag == null) {
            dest.writeByte((byte) (0x02));
        } else {
            dest.writeByte((byte) (flag ? 0x01 : 0x00));
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public static final Parcelable.Creator<BooleanSample> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<BooleanSample>() {
        @Override
        public BooleanSample createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new BooleanSample(in);
        }

        @Override
        public BooleanSample[] newArray(int size) {
            return new BooleanSample[size];
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: `Parcel.writeByte()` uses `Parcel.writeInt()` internally. You should write int values instead.